# How to get rid of a part of an image (an image is a shape) in Photoshop CC?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, mask

I have an image. I want to get rid of "**i**" letter from it.

This is an initial image. It is a shape:

[image]

This is the goal, a desired image:

[image]

I can select and hide "**i**" with a layer mask, but I cannot get rid of the layer mask after that. I end up having two layers, one of them is with a layer mask:

[image]

Also, an important thing is to have Color Picker open on double-click on the final layer of the desired image:

[image]

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Adobe Help: [Working with vector based shape layers](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/atv/cs6-tutorials/working-with-vector-based-shape-layers.html)**

Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) to click **an anchor point** on the path you want removed... hit the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key until that portion is gone (usually takes 2 taps on Delete).

[image]